# Extract goodness of fit from linear mixed effects models

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, lme4-nlme

```
model.1a<-lme(Memory~Clue_words+Words,random=~1|HP_ID,na.action=na.omit,data=soupletters,control=list(opt="optim"))
round(summary(model.1a)$tTable,dig=3)

1a.
Value Std.Error DF t-value p-value
(Intercept)    4.000     0.752 78   5.320   0.000
Clue_wordsyes -1.000     0.346 78  -2.893   0.005
Words          0.269     0.071 78   3.809   0.000

model.1b<-lme(Memory~Clue_words+Words,random=~Order|HP_ID,na.action=na.omit,data=soupletters,control=list(opt="optim"))
round(summary(model.1b)$tTable,dig=3)
anova(model.1a,model.1b)

Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
model.1a     1  5 403.9686 416.8422 -196.9843                        
model.1b     2  7 389.9894 408.0123 -187.9947 1 vs 2 17.97929   1e-04

model.1c<-lme(Memory~Clue_words+Words,random=~1|HP_ID,correlation=corAR1(),na.action=na.omit,data=soupletters,control=list(opt="optim"))
round(summary(model.1c)$tTable,dig=3)
anova(model.1a,model.1c)

Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
model.1a     1  5 403.9686 416.8422 -196.9843                        
model.1c     2  6 391.3869 406.8352 -189.6935 1 vs 2 14.58169   1e-04
```

How can I extract goodness of fit from these models?

Comment: Please be more specific regarding what you need. Are you looking for some kind of pseudo-R-squared?